# Diffeomorphism and bracket?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential

i'm a physics student and i'm studying differential geometry:

I have to prove :

$F_* [X,Y] = [F_* X, F_*Y] $

Where F is a diffeomorphism from G to G where G is a lie group. $F_* $ is the differential of F. X and Y are vector field over G.

I have tried to use definition of differential of a function $ F: M -> N$

$ [(F_*)_p (X_p)] (g) := X_p(g \circ F) $ where $g \in C^{\infty} (N) $ 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please, avoid to use external links and things like that. Try to write the whole question (and context) in the body of your post.

Comment: Ok i'll keep that in mind for future posts

Comment: Surely you can edit the actual post as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, using the definition of pushforward of a vector field by a diffeomorphism, we get: 
 $F_*([X,Y])_q(g)=F_*([X,Y]_{F^{-1}(q)})(g)=[X,Y]_{F^{-1}(q)}(g\circ F)$ 
 $=X_{F^{-1}(q)}(Y(g \circ F))-Y_{F^{-1}(q)}(X(g \circ F))$.

On the other hand:

$[F_*X,F_*Y]_q(g)=F_*(X_{F^{-1}(q)})(F_*Y(g))-F_*(Y_{F^{-1}(q)})(F_*X(g))$

$=X_{F^{-1}(q)}(F_*Y(g)\circ F)-Y_{F^{-1}(q)}(F_*X(g)\circ F)$
$=X_{F^{-1}(q)}(Y(g \circ F))-Y_{F^{-1}(q)}(X(g \circ F))$
In this last step again is used the dfinition of pushforward by $F$.
In case you are not familiar with this concepts (I tried not to ommit any steps and work each side separately so that it was more comprehensible), I recommend you Lee's book, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2013.

Comment: Ok is more clear but i have some problems with the last three steps. Probably because the second and the third one (from the botton) are the same. Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: Where does the $F_*$ from the second to the first step (from the bottom) go?

Comment: You are right, I deleted the repeated line. I have trouble understanding your question. But, whenever I have $F_*$ applyied to a tangent vector and that applied to a function, that's the same as applying the vector to the composition of the function with $F$, just the definition of differential that you enunciated. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: But if i use the definition of differential i obtain this thing:

Comment: Yes but if i try to calculate this: $ (F_* X F_* Y)_q (g) = (F_*)_{F^{-1}(q) } X_{F^{-1} (q)} Y( g \circ F) = X(Y(g \circ F) \circ F)) $ but probabily $F \circ F$ is the same thing of $F$ because $ F: G \rightarrow G $

Comment: @MementoMori, I don't understand what you mean in your sentence. What I did works as well for a diffeomorphism $F: M \rightarrow N$ where $M$, $N$ are different settings, and $F \circ F$ doesn't make sense. You don't need to compose $F \circ F$ at all.

Comment: In general, you can't make $F_*(X_{F^{-1}}(q))$ operate on $Y(g \circ F)$, because the first one is a tangent vector in your other manifold $N$, whilst the second is a function on $M$. Now, in the case $M=N$ it makes sense, but reading my proof you never get to apply that vector to that map. Read it again carefully.

Comment: I see where you got confused. In expressions like $F_*(X_{F^{-1}(q)})(F_*Y(g))$, "$F_*Y(g)$" means the pushforward of $Y$ by $F$ acting on $g$, this is not the same as $Y(g \circ F)$.

Comment: Just to be clear and shed a little more light on this matter, I will show you the difference between $F_*Y(g)$ and $Y(g \circ F)$.

Comment: Assume $F: M \rightarrow N$ and $M$, $N$ are not the same manifold. 
$Y(g \circ F)$ is a function on $M$, and is defined as $Y(g \circ F)(p)=Y_p(g \circ F)$. But $F_*Y(g)$ is a function on $N$, defined as $F_*Y(g)(q)=(F_*Y)_q(g)=F_*(Y_{F^{-1}(q)})(g)=Y_{F^{-1}(q)}(g \circ F)$. So that $Y(g \circ F)$ as a map on $M$ is just the preimage through $F$ of $F_*Y(g)$.

Comment: Thank you man !